# Spring Data not saving @NodeEntity in Neo4J database

Tags: java, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I have the following class to represent my nodes:

```
@NodeEntity(label = "ACCOUNT")
public class N4JAccount implements Serializable {

@Id
private Long id;

public N4JAccount(Account account) {
    this.id = account.getId();
}

public N4JAccount() {
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

Additionally, I have an empty interface which inherits from `Neo4jRepository<N4JAccount, Long>` . I have tried to connect to the database with the same username, password and uri in a different project, there it works without any issues.

I included the following dependencies:

    `implementation group: 'org.neo4j', name: 'neo4j-ogm-http-driver'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j'`
 to my Spring Boot 2.1.5 project.

My uri set in the `application.properties` file is: `bolt://localhost:7687`.

I have been searching for the mistake for hours and I really appreciate your help. Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

- `account.getID()` returns a valid ID
- no Exception is thrown when i run the tests

Comment: Did you try annotating as `import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GeneratedValue;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Id;`  `@Id @GeneratedValue private Long id`?

Comment: I added these annotations quite a while ago and it fixed the issue. But anyway, thanks for your effort.

Comment: did you find any answer for this ?  @JakobHerk

Comment: @SaurabhVerma yes it has been almost 2,5 years but I think I added ```@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)``` to the id.